# How to mock local variables using Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

There are lots of documents to mock a module. However, I want to mock the variables(scoped outside the function) in the same module which I am testing. code below. Any help appreciated

```js
// sample.js
var num1 = 10;
var num2 = 20;

export const add = () => num1 + num2;
export const sub = () => num1 - num2;
export const mul = () => num1 * num2;

// sample.test.js
import { add } from './sample';

test('add', () => {
  var num1 = 5;
  var num2 = 5;
  expect(add()).toEqual(10); // fails as actual value is 30
});
```

Comment: [Don't use global variables](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47923/when-is-it-ok-to-use-a-global-variable), global variables [are bad](https://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad). Problem solved.

Comment: I guess the num1, num2 variables are bound at time of import? Can you do a dynamic `import()` inside the test?

Comment: It would be possible with babel-plugin-rewire but it's in conflict with Jest. You can't and you probably shouldn't. There's no benefit in mocking num1 and num2 in the code above. add, etc just return constant values. If your real case differs from what you showed, consider explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky and not recommended, but if you really need to, you can `eval` the `toString` of the function to essentially "rescope" it:

```js
// sample.js
let add = (function() {
    var num1 = 10;
    var num2 = 20;

    return {
        add() { return num1 + num2; }
    }
})().add;

console.log(add())

var num1 = -1;
var num2 = -3;
console.log(eval('(function ' + add.toString() + ')()'))
```

Comment: how this is related to mocking by Jest

Comment: you can now do `expect(eval('(function ' + add.toString() + ')()')).toEqual(10);`

Comment: yeah, but I can't change the implementation. This is just a sample code as you have guessed.  Just wanted to know if it's possible to mock the module variables which I am testing. 

I can very well move all the variables in another module and mock that module using jest.mock(). but unfortunately cant. Anyway thanks!

Comment: You don't have to change the implementation... I only did that to make it work in the snippet

Comment: Yeah will do it eventually, actual code is huge and complex, and I'm not the owner. However, before taking any step, I wanted to confirm and look like this is not a feasible scenario.